# SSRS Multi-Select Parameter and Like Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a parameter called VoucherType that can multiple values selected by the user at run time. There's a field within the table called Voucher that starts with the VoucherType and ends with a sequence of numbers that I don't care about. For example:

### VoucherTypes

- MKE
- ORD
- LAX

### Vouchers

- MKE-3849284
- MKE-4173942
- ORD-1654951
- LAX-8798484

The SQL query I have to start looks like this:

```
SELECT VOUCHER, COST
FROM VOUCHERDATA
WHERE VOUCHER LIKE @VoucherType + '%';
```

However, it does not support the user selecting multiple values. When they attempt to select multiple values, they get this message:

> Query execution failed for dataset 'Dataset1'. Incorrect syntax near ','.

I'm sure this is because @VoucherType is now a comma delimited list, but I have no clue how to handle it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Note: Table changes are not feasible due to outside constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do in this instance.

First of all you are correct, it is not accepting it because it is now a comma seperated list.

Basically what you need to do is parse out that comma seperated list and use a function with an IN clause in your main query. Here's a very good article explaining how to do this:

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/ssrs_multi_value_parameters

Otherwise another method would be to return everything in your SQL code and filter on the SSRS side. The way to do this would be to remove your where clause in SQL which filters your vouchers. This will then bring back all vouchers. In SSRS then set up a parameter the same way you normally would for a multi select parameter. Then in SSRS design view, you right click your table and go to properties. There is then a tab called filters. You can set up the filter here by saying do not show these vouchers. Basically it hides them.

The first way I explanined is definitely the best way to do it as it is faster and can be re-used in the long run. It is very simple once all the function are setup.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are storing data in First Normal Form (more than one data element in one field) as you have a voucher type and a number in the same field. You probably want to normalize your data into two columns: VoucherType and VoucherID, which would be stored like this:

```
VoucherType | VoucherId
------------------------------
MKE           3849284
MKE           4173942
ORD           1654951
LAX           8798484
```

Now you have a proper column for the report. For convenience, you can create a calculated field to concatenate `VoucherType + '-' + VoucherId` to make queries that need the complete voucher information.

Comment: Unfortunately this is within a huge ERP system, so I'm powerless to make table changes like this, although it's definitely how I would like to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by parsing out the VoucherType on the left side of the equation:

```
SELECT VOUCHER, COST
FROM VOUCHERDATA
WHERE LEFT(VOUCHER,CHARINDEX('-',VOUCHER,1)-1) IN (@VoucherType);
```

With it parsed out, I can use the `IN` keyword appropriately.

Comment: And this is why first normal form requires atomic values. VOUCHERDATA is not even in 1NF. Epic fail on the part of the ERP designers.